# Find a formula for $2^n − 2^{n−1} + 2^{n−2} − 2^{n−3}+\cdots+ (−1)^{n−1}\cdot 2 + (−1)^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, education, geometric-series

I'm having trouble with understanding where to begin, especially since this is my first time with recursions. From my understanding you'd have to match the both equations and simplify until they're equal with each other, or try to apply [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RK9O.png) into the equation of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSUH7.png)? Any hints or advice would be much appreciated!

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RK9O.png) is true for all real numbers r except r = 1 and for all integers n ≥ 0.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: A standard technique for these is to first let $S_n$ be your geometric progression, then compare the expressions for $2S_n$ and $S_n$. What terms do they have in common?

Comment: You have different options. I will consider the case n is even ( we will have to consider n is odd in a second step), and I re-write this sum in opposite order (starting with last term) : $1+ (-2) + (-2)^2 .... + (-2)^n$  :  I think you know how to treat this sum. Another option is to see that we have a suite of many terms, starting with $2^n$, and each new term is the previous one, multiplied by $(-1/2)$

Comment: Hint: it's a geometric series with $n+1$ terms and common ratio $-\frac 12$.

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{i = 0}^n y^i = \frac{1 - y^{n+1}}{1 - y} ~: ~y \neq 1.~$ Here, $~y = -(1/2).$

Answer (score 1):

One can notice that
$$2^n − 2^{n−1} + 2^{n−2} − 2^{n−3}+\cdots+ (−1)^{n−1}\cdot 2 + (−1)^n$$
can be seen as:
\begin{align}
S &= 2^n − 2^{n−1} + 2^{n−2} − 2^{n−3}+\cdots+ (−1)^{n−1}\cdot 2 + (−1)^n \\
&= 2^n + (-1)^1 \, 2^{n-1} + (-1)^2 \, 2^{n-2} + \cdots + (-1)^{n-1} \, 2^{n - (n-1)} + (-1)^n \, 2^{n - n} \\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^j \, 2^{n-j} \\
&= 2^{n} \, \sum_{j=0}^{n} \left(- \frac{1}{2}\right)^j = 2^{n} \, \frac{1 - (-1/2)^{n+1}}{1 + \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{3} \, (2^{n+1} - (-1)^{n+1}) \\
&= J_{n+1}.
\end{align}

Note that:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{n} t^j &= \frac{1 - t^{n+1}}{1-t} \\
J_{n} &= \frac{2^n - (-1)^n}{3} \hspace{5mm} \text{Jacobsthal numbers}.
\end{align}

Further information about the Jacobsthal numbers can be found at [Oeis A001045](https://oeis.org/A001045).